# $_REQUEST и главный файл

Tags: php

Допустим, у меня есть файл install.php, и у install.php 5 $_REQUEST

То есть:

```
$_REQUEST['step'] 5 штук. step=1; step=2; step=3; step=4; step=5
```

Как мне сделать чтобы отображался исходный код страницы (install.php), а так же если забили в адресную строку install.php?step=1, то содержимое меняется. Так же, как организовать функцию ограничения step. Тоесть со step=1 нельзя перейти на step=3, а так же ограничения, что stepoв всего 5 и они не могут быть отрицательны.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может что-то типа этого?

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['step'])){
    switch($_REQUEST['step']){
    case '1':
        $_SESSION['step_'] = 1;
        //Шаг 1

    break;
    case '2':
        if($_SESSION['step_'] == 1){
        $_SESSION['step_'] = 12;
            //Шаг 2

        }else{
            exit();
        }
    break;
    case '3':
        if($_SESSION['step_'] == 12){
        $_SESSION['step_'] = 123;
            //Шаг 3

        }else{
            exit();
        }
    break;
    case '4':
        if($_SESSION['step_'] == 123){
        $_SESSION['step_'] = 1234;
            //Шаг 4

        }else{
            exit();
        }
    break;
    case '5':
        if($_SESSION['step_'] == 12345){
        $_SESSION['step_'] = 12345;
            //Шаг 5

        }else{
            exit();
        }
    break;
    }
}else{
//Error
}
?>
```

Comment: ты не указал самое главное. Чтобы при своём step'е было своё содержимое. echo лишь добавит выше основного.

Comment: вместо "//Шаг n" указываешь свое содержимое

Comment: Кошмар. Я далеко не гуру php, но неужели нет других вариантов решения, с меньшим количеством г****кода?

Вот даже не пожалею времени и попробую это реализовать.

Comment: @1101_debian, я особо не напрягался (не получилось напрячься :D)

Ну давай-давай, реализовывай, заценим, твой "чудо" код.

Comment: Это всеголишь убогая попытка реализация недо-фротнтконтроллера...

Собственно какой вопрос такой и ответ, чего-же вы хотели?
****
Я не утверждаю что это нормальный код, но для такой задачи - покатит =)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
    $views = array('home.html', 'profile.html', 'about.html');
    include $views[$_REQUEST['step']];
    echo 'Came from => '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
?>
```

Способ выводить разное содержимое в зависимости от параметров.
Массив содержит в себе имена файлов (вьюх) в которых хранится нужная информация для конкретного шага.
Предпоследняя строка выводит URL с которого пришел пользователь, в конкретной вьюхе можно ее проверять.
Но и это не самый лучший вариант, уверен что есть более адекватные средства, но я их не знаю, т.к. далек от пхп.

Comment: @1101_debian - примерно так это и делается.

Но это хоть на программирование похоже, т.к. то что выше больше похоже на мета-описание =)

Comment: Вы задание внимательно прочитали?

Comment: Elime, да, а что не так?

Comment: @1101_debian, ну в задании написано что нельзя перейти с первого step'a сразу на третий/любой другой. То есть переходить можно только по-порядку с первого по пятый. У вас же можно гулять по всем, без ограничений.

Comment: @Elime - допустим невнимательно он прочитал задание, тем не менее - можно было-бы создать отдельные скрипты для каждого степа и подключать их если такой файл существует, если нет - светить legendary 404.

Допустим таких шагов стало 200, что бы вы делали? Писали бы 200 разветвлений свитча? Как не печально, но:

     Повторное использование кода ~= 0 && гибкость ~= 0 === true

По поводу перехода по порядку - достаточно добавить еще одно условие, т.е. 

     if(file_exists($stepvalue . '.php') && $_SESSION['step'] == ($_GET['step'] - 1))

Comment: А вообще подобные вещи необходимо реализовывать без использования гет параметров
****
одна точка входа + сессия, больше ничего не нужно

Comment: @AlexWindHope, facepalm.. 

Я выполнял конкретное задание, в задании указано, что только 5(!) степов. Этот код отличается только тем, что каждый степ находится в отдельном файле и инклюдится в еще один файл, и в кажом файле опять же будут те проверки, которые я написал в свичах. Где профит?!

----------------------------------------

там $_REQUEST, а не $_GET

Comment: Ну если вы такой внимательный, то прочтите и мой ответ тоже, я там где-то писал про предпоследнюю строчку, про HTTP_REFERER в общем. Но можно и в сессию записывать. А уже непосредственно в конкретной вьюхепроверять предыдущую страничку, и в случае ошибки редиректить на "главную" страницу (step=0).

Вариантов много. Свое решение я предоставил как альтернативу Вашему ужасному switch'у, еще и с кучей if'ов.

Comment: if(file_exists($stepvalue . '.php') && $_SESSION['step'] == ($_GET['step'] - 1))

я перейду на первый степ и будет ошибка

----------------------------

> Ну если вы такой внимательный, то прочтите и мой ответ тоже, я там где-то писал про предпоследнюю строчку, про HTTP_REFERER в общем.

А если я наберу адрес в адресной строке, а не перейду по ссылке?

Comment: А если я наберу адрес в адресной строке, а не перейду по ссылке? - реферер пустой будет.

Свичи уже запрещено использовать? - Нет, можно, но такие свичи - говнокод в чистом виде, и это не только мое мнение, нет.

Кэп здесь: реферер пустой, а значит пришли не по ссылке, а значит ошибка.

Comment: @Elime я вообще не вникал в задание, я просто посмотрел на тот ужас который вы написали и сделал соответствующие выводы (что код редкое Г и писать такое, а тем более использовать в реале, крайне не рекомендуется)

Ответ принят посему не вижу для себя мотивации садится и писать по человечески.

По поводу степов - сегодня их 5, завтра их надо будет 10, послезавтра 15, вы не умеете либо не желаете мыслить наперед. По своему опыту скажу - код написаный в вашем стиле в 99% случае правится и в 99% случаев - мягко говоря не раз.

Печально то что вы считаете что ваш код действительно хорош...

Comment: Шагов нужно 5, они используются для инсталляции скрипта. Как бы не выглядел код, он работает, а если работает, то лучше не трогать :)

Comment: Дмитрий, как хорошо что есть "кодеры" с такими взглядами